# Permission report at Azure DevOps Repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to get audit report with users and permissions for each users for Azure DevOps repository? Is there any API or SDK that I can use? I'm ready to write some C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try

```
https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{YOUR_ORGANIZATION}/_apis/audit/actions
```

from [this document](https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/%7BYOUR_ORGANIZATION%7D/_apis/audit/actions).

Comment: Thanks for adding answer. Looks like link has broken, could you please point me with the document.